# C++ Triangle Project

Tags: c++

I have this project for my programming class that I've been having trouble getting to work. Basically, I have to determine whether or not based off the numbers that the user gives me if the triangle is equilateral,isosceles or scalene. There are certain conditions where if one side = 0 it is not a triangle.but the only problem i am having is that whenever i enter 3 equal numbers it displays These sides do not form a triangle All sides must be greater than zero. im not sure why ive been stuck here for 2 hrs

`if ((usernum1 == 0) && (usernum2 == 0) && (usernum3 == 0)){
cout<<"These sides do not form a triangle."<<endl;
            cout<<"All sides must be greater than zero."<<end
}`

`else if (usernum1,usernum2 == usernum3){
        cout<<"It is "<<endl;
            cout<<"an equilateral triangle because all sides are equal."<<endl;
}`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhRHP.jpg "cmd output"
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4goqy.jpg "my code without any statements"

Comment: No, that's not the only problem you're having. For starters, your first `if()` condition is wrong, given your description of what it has to do. Take out a piece of paper, and a pencil. Set `usernum1` to 0, all others to some non-zero value, then work out, on paper, how the `if` statement is going to evaluate. Hint: it's not going to evaluate to `true`.

Comment: `else if(usernum1, usernum2 == usernum3)` that's not how it works. You must restate the condition for every comparison: `else if(usernum1 == usernum3 && usernum2 == usernum3)`. Also, look at your first if. You are looking for the `||` operator, to see if any one of them is 0.

Comment: Yes thanks for the reply, im going to redo my code from the start